# Cant log on to Metasploitable 2 into VM ware

Tags: virtual-machine

I  downloaded the zip file of Metasploitabe2 in to the downloads folder, and then un zipped it to my desktop. On vm ware, i clicked to open a virtual machine, navigated to the location where i unzipped it.There was only vmx file there , so i then powered on the VM.
When i tried to put the US name then entered ok, but the password nothing was able to input.
UN and PW msfadmin

Please advice what i need to do to get it working.
Kindly note im am a new student in this field.

Comment: There was only vmx file there .  It appears the VMDK (machine file) is missing. Check your ZIP file for the large VMDK file.

Comment: @John - If the author was able to power on the VM that suggests the virtual HDD exists, otherwise, it wouldn’t have powdered on. I suspect the question is missing some significant amount of details.

Comment: Hi to @John and Ramhound  I  have checked the zip file, from down loads, unzipped to my folder on Desktop. I have deleted / remove the previous vm from the VM platform in order to avoid confusion. Now I clicked on ," Open a virtual Machine " navigate to the folder on my desktop, and there is only Metasploitable.vmx . I am then able to the process to load the machine, but the same occurs. Username  then entered ok, but the password nothing was able to input. UN and PW msfadmin. If i put my mouse / cursor to where i should type my password, and click there nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing. It just doesn't show the cursor moving or even asterisks so that people can't see the length of your password. If you type the full password correctly and hit enter it will allow you to log in.